# Override "includes/index.php" in wordpress child-theme

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, overriding

I can't override `includes/index.php` in my WordPress child-theme. This file is declared in parent-theme function like this:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/index.php';
```

For more information, I can override the other files like `template/test.php` and so on without any problem.

Comment: Where (file and function) is parent theme requiring this file?

Comment: The parent theme is requiring the file in functions.php like this : require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/index.php';

Comment: But it is being called inside some function, isn't it? Otherwise it will be called in every page.

Comment: Its not called in any function, and its called in an other page with same way (with a require once).